# metric space with one limit point

Tags: real-analysis

all sets are clopen in the metric space with a single limit point?

I think it is not the case, but I'm not sure which space has a single limit point. I was thinking of convergent sequences and singletons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Let $X$ be the space. Suppose that $p$ is a limit point of $X\setminus\{p\}$; is $\{p\}$ a clopen set?

(By the way, one can’t legitimately speak of *the* metric spaces with a single limit point: there are many such spaces.)

Comment: So p is in the closure and is closed?

Comment: @Bob: $p$ is in the closure of $X\setminus\{p\}$, by the definition of *limit point*. Is what closed? $p$ is just a point, not a subset of $X$, so closedness isn’t a property that it can have. Are you asking whether $\{p\}$ is closed? The answer to that is *yes*: in a metric space every singleton is closed.

Comment: sorry, that's what I meant, {p} is just closed and not both closed and open. Thanks!

Comment: @Bob: Yes, that’s right. You’re welcome!